# Can I ingest data into tables in azure data explorer through Databricks?

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-data-explorer

I have to ingest data from ADLS gen2 to tables in ADX.
I first tried to use ADF, but considering the run time and everything, this was an really inefficient way to do it.
I think it would be so much easier if there is a way to ingest data into ADX via databricks.
I only can access ADLS through Service Pricipals so I can't directly connect to the storage account from ADX.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Does the SP have access to the ADLS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is for continuous ingestion consider creating an [Event Grid data connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-event-grid?tabs=adx)

If it is for one-time ingestion consider using the "[lightIngest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/lightingest)" tool, and provide the applicable connection string for your use case.

Comment: sorry I have a limited access to the adls storage account so I only can access there through SP. Can I still use event grid here to ingest data from adls to adx tables?

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend the [Event Grid Data connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-event-grid-overview). Please note that you can set up this data connection using managed identities.